# how to control help file generation for WCF 4 REST Service?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, rest, wcf-4

I have written a WCF Rest Service that uses XmlSerializer. 
I have also implemented IXmlSerializable on the type I am accepting as a service parameter. 
The serialization works great. 
However the help files that WCF generates by default do not work. when i navigate to : myservice/help i only see this:

> Could not generate schema document.

So is it possible to control what gets generated ? Perhaps there is something I'm missing to make the help files generate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to control help files generation. Most likely, there is no way. But you can disable default help files generation in configs and map to /help paths your custom logic. It may use some reflection or be hard-coded, but you will get what you want - control over help pages generation